# Is a URL which uses a Rewrite URL still searchable by search engines?

Tags: url-rewriting

My developer did the following:

If someone types public.sample.com/user/chumbawumba it redirects to stage.sample.com/profile.php?username=chumbawumba

I want to make sure that the content of the profile -- which contains company information for example, is searchable on the public.sample.com domain name.

He used a Rewrite Rule.

I guess I wasn't anticipating this approach, but as long as the pages can get spidered and ranked as more information is put in, I'm cool with it.

I tried to run an online sitemap on the site and I don't think it came up with anything, thus my question.  Thanks.

Comment: public.sample.com/user/chumbawumba is a better URL for SEO

Answer (score 1):

You could go to google and type "site: public.sample.com" to see all pages searched with google on your site. Also see [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

Please tell is the rule redirets or rewrites request? So could you see in your browser "stage.sample.com/profile.php?username=chumbawumba" or "public.sample.com/user/chumbawumba".

If all you could see is "public.sample.com/user/chumbawumba" - that is OK. If not - same will be seen with search bot.

Comment: what I see is stage.sample.com/profile.php?username-chumbawumba...what do I need to correct this?
Google webmaster sees nothing at the site....

Comment: Please tell developer to use "Rewrite Rule" not "Redirect Rule". http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html - "The rewritten result can lead to internal sub-processing, external request redirection". You need "internal sub-processing".

Answer (score 0):

This technique is a common technique used by SEO people/companies because then the search engine will not have send the ?... and many search engines will ignore, so Yes.

Comment: thanks -- so should an online xml sitemap creator still pick up the URLs or do I need another way to enable google to crawl it?

Comment: Don't submit multiple URLs for the same page in your sitemap

Answer (score 0):

Anyway URL with "?" is indexed with google.
Look at [faq on URLs with queries](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=76329).

Search for "profile test" and you will see results with "?" inside URL.